# When i am trying to add proxy at file side (i.e) source view

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am facing error like below at esb terminal side,i done many things like rename file so and so...... then also i didnt get any thing.

ERROR - ProxyServiceFactory Target is required for a Proxy service definition.

WARN - ProxyServiceDeployer Proxy service hot deployment from file: /home/aa/Downloads/jack/LatestVersion/wso2esb-4.6.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/readings.xml failed - Continue in fail-safe mode

org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Target is required for a Proxy service definition
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ProxyServiceFactory.handleException(ProxyServiceFactory.java:369)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ProxyServiceFactory.createProxy(ProxyServiceFactory.java:220)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.ProxyServiceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ProxyServiceDeployer.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.ProxyServiceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ProxyServiceDeployer.java:73)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:810)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Comment: It might be because your synapse configuration is wrong can you share the configuration as well.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="insertreadings"
          transports="https http"
          startOnLoad="true"
          trace="disable">
             <description/>
            <target>

Comment: /home/aa/Downloads/jack/LatestVersion/wso2esb-4.6.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/readings.xml

Answer (score 0):

A Proxy Service should contain at least an Insequence or an Endpoint or both. Make sure your file has atleast the following basic format which uses an empty insequence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="ProxyName"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence/>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Can you please give the whole code otherwise its impossible to debug whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting above error as you didn't set the namespace correctly on the proxy service definition.

Can you add namespace as follows (with "http://"):

```
xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
```

Comment: xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" same thing i already given..then also it is showing same eroor.

Comment: I'm not mentioning about the semicolon ';'. Can you just add the 'http://' to the namespace? without 'http' you cannot save the proxy service

Comment: Can you show your current proxy definition line of your configuration

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="insertreadings"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target> 
    <inSequence>  
      </target>   </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <drop/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>

Comment: Why is there a </target> inside the <inSequence>. Other than that, your configuration works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try after fixing your configuration as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="insertreadings"
   transports="https,http"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
<description/>
<target>
  <inSequence/>
  <outSequence>
     <drop/>
  </outSequence>
</target>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Do you continue to get the same error? Can you pls send in your proxy config and the error you get?

Answer (score -1):

i see a semicolon ";" in your proxy configurations. Can you remove that and try? just before name

```
    <proxy xmlns="ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"; 
           name="insertreadings" 
           transports="https http" 
           startOnLoad="true" 
           trace="disable">
```